# Windows Server 2008 SP2 Task Scheduler problems

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a series of scheduled tasks that have been running fine until about 2 months ago.  Now they seem to run sometimes, at the scheduled time, but not consistently. The tasks will run if I reboot the server but not if the server has been left on for some time.  I suspect a Windows update has caused the problem but having investiigated all the updates installed I cannot see which might have caused the problem. I've checked all permissions etc and am happy that everything is set OK - and the fact that the tasks will all run after a reboot confirms that the settings are fine.  Anybody else have this problem?

Comment: Move your question to SUPERUSER. It doesn't belong here.

Comment: Which operating system? Server 2008 and Server 2008R2 are different in the same way Windows Vista is different from Windows 7.